# Theme android Transparent Navigation Bar and No Title bar

Tags: android, android-theme

I have tried many themes also tried to customize one but could not manage to make **Transparent Navigation Bar** (buttons) **without Fullscreen** (I have buttons above the navigation so they will overlap if it is fullscreen) and **without Title or ActionBar**. How can i make this?

```
<style name="Theme.TransparencyDemo" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
```

Comment: post your code here ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?